# django: how to display list of checkboxes for one-to-many relationship?

Tags: django, django-forms

Say that `Blog` model has a one-to-many relationship with `Entry` model. In a form, is there an elegant way display the set of Entries for a Blog instance as a list of checkboxes, so the user may select and process some/all of the Entries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    entries = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Entry.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Blog

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BlogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog=blog)
            self.fields['entries'].queryset = entries
```